# QML dynamic scoping not working (ReferenceError)

Tags: application-development, c++, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am trying to reproduce the example [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/QtQml.qtqml-documents-scope/) where the **TitlePage.qml** component creates two **TitleText** instances even though the **TitleText** type is in a separate file (under Section: Component Instance Hierarchy).
In the Ubuntu SDK I created a new project (QML App with C++ plugin (qmake)).  My **Main.qml** looks like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2
import ScopeTesting 1.0

MainView {
    objectName: "mainView"
    applicationName: "scopetesting.username"
    width: units.gu(100)
    height: units.gu(75)
    Item {
        property string title
        TitleText {
            size: 22
            anchors.top: parent.top
        }
        TitleText {
            size: 18
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        }
    }
}
```

The **TitleText.qml** looks like the example:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import Ubuntu.Components 1.2
import ScopeTesting 1.0

Text {
    property int size
    text: "<b>" + title + "</b>"
    font.pixelSize: size
}
```

What I get is a ReferenceError:

> ...TitleText.qml:7: ReferenceError: title is not defined

What am I missing here? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object can't use the properties of other objects directly unless they belong to the root object of the file.

Move `property string title` to `MainView` or give an id to `Item` and use `title` through the id.

Comment: I thought `TitleText` could access the `title` because it is a child of `Item`.  I dont understand, how I am missunderstanding the [documentation](https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/QtQml.qtqml-documents-scope/) `Each QML component in a QML document defines a logical scope`.  Is `Item` not a component?

Comment: `The component scope is the union of the object ids within the component and the component's root object's properties.` It doesn't say anything about the properties of the non-root objects.